# Database Size is Different after pg_restore (389 GB vs 229 GB)

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-dump, postgresql-11, pg-restore

I created a backup of my database in a PostgreSQL 11.6 (with TimescaleDB 1.60 extension) using `pg_dump`:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -h 127.22.0.4 -p 5432 -U postgres -Z0 -Fc database_development
```

and restored it to a new server running the same versions of PostgreSQL 11.6 (with TimescaleDB 1.60 extension) using `pg_restore`. For the restore, executed the following commands in `psql` as user `postgres`:

```
CREATE DATABASE database_development;
\c database_development
CREATE EXTENSION timescaledb;
SELECT timescaledb_pre_restore();

\! time pg_restore -Fc -d database_development /var/lib/postgresql/backups/database_development_2020-02-29

SELECT timescaledb_post_restore();
```

The database size of the original database was 389 GB but the restored database was 229 GB. These sizes were obtained by running

```
select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('database_development'))
```

**Some differences:**

The old database is stored on a ext4 partition, while the new database is stored on a ZFS filesystem with compression disabled. Both database instances are running inside a Docker container with an Ubuntu 18.04 host.

**Question:** How can we explain the differences in the database sizes? There were no errors encountered during both the `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

Comment: Dump doesn’t account for dead tuples and only takes live tuples into account but dead tuples do account for space hence the space difference.

Comment: @RajVerma Is it usual for dead tuples to account for ~ 30% of all tuples?

Comment: It all depends on how many rows you touch with the modification(update, deletes etc.) operations in postgres.

Comment: I have seen dbs to be bloated with 800 gigs on a 1.5 tb and much more on a 10 tb db if not maintained properly, remember when dead rows are removed space is not reclaimed by vacuum just so it can be reused, dump only creates statements which will not be the case with a base backup(physical) see answer below, hope this helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dump doesn’t account for dead tuples and only takes live tuples into account but dead tuples do account for space hence the space difference.

The reason is dump being a logical one it will only create statements to insert your data and the dead rows would anyways be invisible to it. If you have lots of updates and deletes happening or in other words your db is highly transactional, it will create more dead row versions and needs an aggressive vacuum to deal with bloating as well. If and when you compare the dead vs live row counts, before and after the restore you will see the difference.

Also just to be on a safer side do perform a manual vacuum analyse on the db post a dump restore, i have seen in the past that due to wrong estimation the planner changes the optimum plan to be used for the queries.